# How can I improve real-time response on an ARM processor?

Tags: arm, linux, jitter

Why do my attempts to run a 1ms timer with low jitter fail? How can I improve it?

---

I am working on an STM32MP1, but it should be similar on a more common Raspberry Pi board.

The goal is to have some hardware responding in hard real time (<50us) to IO events, so I am trying to assess how doable is to use user-mode or kernel-mode for this. It might be that testing with an OS clock is the problem. If you think so, let me know.

Note: The STM32MP1 has a type M4 real time core. That core will be dedicated to other tasks. I am aware of that M4 core but I can't use it here.

The board has a PREEMPT_RT Linux kernel installed.

**Attempt 1: using cyclictest**

```
cyclictest --mlockall -t -a --priority=99 --interval=200 --distance=0 -l 0
```

I get mostly `27us` delay `+-10us` jitter, but stressing a bit the system and waiting long enough, it jumps to hundreds us, and I even once saw `1.4ms`.

**Attempt 2: building a Linux kernel module:**

I created a kernel module, which I load on the PREEMPT_RT Linux kernel:

```
/*
 * Simplest jitter histogram ever
 */

#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/hrtimer.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/math64.h> /* for 64bit division*/

static struct hrtimer msTimer;
static ktime_t interval_duration;
static ktime_t interval_start_time, module_start_time;
static u64 iteration_count;

static int histogram[6]; //<0.1us, 0.1-1, 1-10, 10-100, 100-1000, >1000

static enum hrtimer_restart timer_callback(struct hrtimer* msTimer)
{
    ktime_t end;           
    s64 diff_time;
    u32 remIt;
    
    /*Restart timer for next iteration asap*/
    hrtimer_forward_now(msTimer, interval_duration);
    
    /*Calculate the interval duration*/
    end = ktime_get();
    diff_time = ktime_to_ns(ktime_sub(end, interval_start_time)) - interval_duration;
    interval_start_time = end;
    
    /*Update histogram*/
    if (diff_time<100) histogram[0]++;
    else if (diff_time<1000) histogram[1]++;
    else if (diff_time<10000) histogram[2]++;
    else if (diff_time<100000) histogram[3]++;
    else if (diff_time<1000000) histogram[4]++;
    else histogram[5]++;
    
    /*Print histogram every 10s or so*/
    div_u64_rem(++iteration_count, 10000, &remIt);
    if (remIt == 0)
    {
        pr_info("HISTOGRAM: %d    %d    %d    %d   %d   %d\n",
            histogram[0], histogram[1], histogram[2], histogram[3], histogram[4], histogram[5]);
    }

    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

int init_module(void)
{
    int i;
    
    iteration_count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<6; ++i) histogram[i] = 0;
    
    /*Start timer of 1ms*/
    interval_duration = ktime_set(0, 1000000); //seconds,nanoseconds
    hrtimer_init (& msTimer, CLOCK_REALTIME, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
    msTimer.function = timer_callback;
    hrtimer_start(& msTimer, interval_duration, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
    module_start_time = interval_start_time = ktime_get();    
    
    pr_info("CybJitter 0.1\n");
    
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    ktime_t end; 
    s64 diff_time;
    
    /* Stop timer*/
    hrtimer_cancel(& msTimer);
    
    /*Some final stats*/
    pr_info("Iterations: %lld\n",(long long)iteration_count);    
    end = ktime_get();
    diff_time = ktime_to_ns(ktime_sub(end, module_start_time));
    pr_info("Total time elapsed: %lld\n",(long long)diff_time);
    
    pr_info("CybJitter 0.1: Bye!.\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

The output is something like:

```
           <0.1us    0.1-1us  1-10us   10-100us 0.1-1ms  >1ms
HISTOGRAM: 143471    40403    32139    3429     425      133
Iterations: 228549
Total time elapsed: 228954226530
```

Which indicate that about 0.1% of the samples arrive 1ms late or more, which is worse than with `cyclictest`.

**Attempt 3:**

I can use `ndelay` to wakeup before and adjust up to the exact time, however, I fear that this is just a patch and any further jitter will still destroy my hard real time.

---

Where is this jitter coming from? What can I try to improve this? Is it possible the jitter down to a few microseconds?

---

EDIT:

Attempt 3: External hardware clock and measurement.

I created a kernel module reacting to an external signal (GPIO).

I am generating the input with the oscilloscope and reading both: the input and the output in that same oscilloscope. The jitter is still very bad. I was expecting some <100us maximum response time.. but.

[image]

```
#include <linux/gpio.h> 
#include <linux/interrupt.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/printk.h> 
#include <linux/delay.h>
 
static int button_irqs[] = { -1, -1 }; 
 
static struct gpio leds[] = { { 26, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "LED 1" } }; 
 
static struct gpio buttons[] = { { 3, GPIOF_IN, "LED 1 OFF BUTTON" } }; 
 
/* interrupt function triggered when a input is raised. */ 
static irqreturn_t button_isr(int irq, void *data) 
{ 

    gpio_set_value(leds[0].gpio,1);
    udelay(1);
    gpio_set_value(leds[0].gpio,0);
    
    return IRQ_HANDLED; 
} 
 
static int __init intrpt_init(void) 
{ 
    int ret = 0; 
 
    pr_info("%s\n", __func__); 
 
    /* register output gpios */ 
    ret = gpio_request_array(leds, ARRAY_SIZE(leds)); 
 
    if (ret) { 
        pr_err("Unable to request GPIOs for LEDs: %d\n", ret); 
        return ret; 
    } 
 
    /* register inputgpios */ 
    ret = gpio_request_array(buttons, ARRAY_SIZE(buttons)); 
 
    if (ret) { 
        pr_err("Unable to request GPIOs for BUTTONs: %d\n", ret); 
        goto fail1; 
    } 
 
 
    /* INPUT */
    pr_info("Current button1 value: %d\n", gpio_get_value(buttons[0].gpio)); 
 
    ret = gpio_to_irq(buttons[0].gpio); 
 
    if (ret < 0) { 
        pr_err("Unable to request IRQ: %d\n", ret); 
        goto fail2; 
    } 
 
    button_irqs[0] = ret; 
 
    pr_info("Successfully requested BUTTON1 IRQ # %d\n", button_irqs[0]); 
 
    ret = request_irq(button_irqs[0], button_isr, 
                      IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING  | IRQF_SHARED /*| IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING*/, 
                      "gpiomod#button1", NULL); 
 
    if (ret) { 
        pr_err("Unable to request IRQ: %d\n", ret); 
        goto fail2; 
    } 
    
    irq_set_affinity_hint(button_isr, cpumask_of(0));
 
    if (ret < 0) { 
        pr_err("Unable to request IRQ: %d\n", ret); 
        goto fail2; 
    } 
 
    button_irqs[1] = ret; 
 
    pr_info("Successfully requested BUTTON2 IRQ # %d\n", button_irqs[1]); 
 
    ret = request_irq(button_irqs[1], button_isr, 
                      IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, 
                      "gpiomod#button2", NULL); 
 
    if (ret) { 
        pr_err("Unable to request IRQ: %d\n", ret); 
        goto fail3; 
    } */
 
    return 0; 
 
/* cleanup what has been setup so far */ 
fail3: 
    free_irq(button_irqs[0], NULL); 
 
fail2: 
    gpio_free_array(buttons, ARRAY_SIZE(leds)); 
 
fail1: 
    gpio_free_array(leds, ARRAY_SIZE(leds)); 
 
    return ret; 
} 
 
static void __exit intrpt_exit(void) 
{ 
    int i; 
 
    pr_info("%s\n", __func__); 
 
    /* free irqs */ 
    free_irq(button_irqs[0], NULL); 
 
    /* turn all LEDs off */ 
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(leds); i++) 
        gpio_set_value(leds[i].gpio, 0); 
 
    /* unregister */ 
    gpio_free_array(leds, ARRAY_SIZE(leds)); 
    gpio_free_array(buttons, ARRAY_SIZE(buttons)); 
} 
 
module_init(intrpt_init); 
module_exit(intrpt_exit); 
 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Handle some GPIO interrupts");
```

Comment: Linux by default is not  real-time OS.

Comment: That's why I am using Preempt-RT kernel. I still don't expect sub-us response, but I wonder if I can get to some few <10 us of jitter.

Comment: possible, but unlikely to be guaranteeable. https://www.jblopen.com/arm-cortex-a-interrupt-latency/ has an empiric study of cortex-A9 hardware interrupt latencies; unlike in cortex-M, the interrupt latency in cortex-A processors has to take external memory, pending bus transfers and other sources of uncertainty into account. (you need to completely switch out your context which means loading a complete image from the TLB!). And that's the hardware site, not incorporating what the Linux kernel itself has to do to service an interrupt request.

Comment: That article is interesting, but the `max` there are at <5us. While my limit are now over 1.4ms. I would be very happy with a guaranteed 20us.

Comment: But don't those timers run in some sort of timer task and software queue, executing after more important things have been executed? It's not like the driver responds to a hardware timer interrupt? Sounds like asking too much if you are not running on a hardware timer.

Comment: again, that's a nearly-bare-metal RTOS, so what you see is mostly hardware latency. In your case, a much more complex code path is between the interrupt source and your counters :) also, can you avoid doing the integer division in the interrupt routine, that would leave a warm and fuzzy feeling about the test methodology in me (you could instead simply `if(!(++iteration_count & (1 << 13 - 1))))`

Comment: @Justme: I will try to make the test on hardware timer.
@MarcusMüller: I run `hrtimer_forward_now` at the beginning, the division has a full 1ms to return. Actually, I am much more worried about the logging process.

Comment: I created a kernel module with an IRQ responding on an external hardware clock. I still have very high jitter (>100us several times per minute).